# Compare value in three array and get specific value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am comparing three value in an array and i am getting all value.

How can i output specific value or value that i only want to output

Because i want to output value that i only nedeed.

I have this code:

```
<?php
$participants = [
    [   'calleridnum' => 1,
        'callee' => 'yay' 
    ],
    [   'calleridnum' => 2,
        'callee' => 'yay' 
    ],
     [  'calleridnum' => 3,
        'callee' => 'yay' 
    ]
];
$conferance_participants = [
    [   'uid' => 1,
        'caller' => 'yay2',
        'dit' => 'deze'
    ],
    [   'uid' => 2,
        'caller' => 'test',
        'dit' => 'wew'
    ]
];
$contacts = [
    [   'name' => 1,
        'test' => 'yay2',
        'limit' => 1
    ],
    [   'name' => 2,
        'test' => 'yay2',
        'limit' => 1
    ]
];



    foreach ($participants as $participant=>$p) {
        foreach ($conferance_participants as $conferance_participant=>$cp) {
            foreach ($contacts as $contact=>$cs) {

                if (($p['calleridnum'] == $cp['uid']) && ($cp['uid'] == $cs['name'])){
                     $conferance_participants[$conferance_participant] = array_merge(
                     $participants[$participant],
                     $conferance_participants[$conferance_participant],
                     $contacts[$contact]
                );

                }
            } 

        } 

    }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($conferance_participants);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

and my output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 1
            [callee] => yay
            [uid] => 1
            [caller] => yay2
            [dit] => deze
            [name] => 1
            [test] => yay2
            [limit] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 2
            [callee] => yay
            [uid] => 2
            [caller] => test
            [dit] => wew
            [name] => 2
            [test] => yay2
            [limit] => 1
        )

)
```

I want ot minimize my output.

I want to remove `name` `test` from the $contacts array

I also want to remove `caller` `dit` from the $conferance_participants array

so that my output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 1
            [callee] => yay
            [uid] => 1
            [limit] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 2
            [callee] => yay
            [uid] => 2
            [limit] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: I've never seen an array declared like that before

Comment: @ScottMcGready It's a shorthand way new in 5.4 (I think that's the version number).

Comment: @chris85 it's absolutely horrid and just open to issues and confusion. Personal opinion of course and not an attack on OP at all.

Comment: Are you using the separate arrays later? If you take out the identifiers it is going to be hard to identify. Maybe just make one array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is hard to understand,

Number of times your `foreach` will execute,

```
count($participants) * count($conferance_participants) * count($contacts);
```

Number of times this code's `foreach` will execute will be equal or less than your codes, because it will stop as soon as the match found.

Also i have created a new function, for searching in another arrays, so it will make the next person working on this code less bang his head on the desk.

Passes `$conferance_participants` variable's value as reference, note the **`&`** in foreach declaration so no need to worry about keys of the array.

```
foreach($conferance_participants as &$record) {
    # find keys of corresponding array matches
    $key_in_participants = _custom_search($record['uid'], $participants, 'calleridnum');
    $key_in_contacts = _custom_search($record['uid'], $contacts, 'name');

    # unset unwanted things
    unset($record['caller'], $record['dit']);

    # activate this code if you want to make false for unmatched records
    /* ***********************************************************************
    if($key_in_participants === false || $key_in_contacts === false) {
        $record['calleridnum'] = $record['callee'] = $record['limit'] = false;
        continue;
    }
    *********************************************************************** */ 

    # setting required things
    $record['calleridnum'] = $participants[$key_in_participants]['calleridnum'];
    $record['callee'] = $participants[$key_in_participants]['callee'];
    $record['limit'] = $contacts[$key_in_contacts]['limit'];
}

function _custom_search($id, $array, $key_to_search) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) if($val[$key_to_search] === $id) return $key;
   return false;
}
```

This will make `$conferance_participants` exactly as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just unset the array keys before you merge the arrays. Then set the 'name' key again for $contacts array which is needed for the loops above.

Here is the modified code sample:

```
<?php

    $participants = [
        [   'calleridnum' => 1,
            'callee' => 'yay'
        ],
        [   'calleridnum' => 2,
            'callee' => 'yay'
        ],
         [  'calleridnum' => 3,
            'callee' => 'yay'
        ]
    ];
    $conferance_participants = [
        [   'uid' => 1,
            'caller' => 'yay2',
            'dit' => 'deze'
        ],
        [   'uid' => 2,
            'caller' => 'test',
            'dit' => 'wew'
        ]
    ];
    $contacts = [
        [   'name' => 1,
            'test' => 'yay2',
            'limit' => 1
        ],
        [   'name' => 2,
            'test' => 'yay2',
            'limit' => 1
        ]
    ];

        foreach ($participants as $participant=>$p) {
            foreach ($conferance_participants as $conferance_participant=>$cp) {
                foreach ($contacts as $contact=>$cs) {

                    if (($p['calleridnum'] == $cp['uid']) && ($cp['uid'] == $cs['name'])){

                         unset($contacts[$contact]['name'], $contacts[$contact]['test']);
                         unset($conferance_participants[$conferance_participant]['caller'], $conferance_participants[$conferance_participant]['dit']);

                         $conferance_participants[$conferance_participant] = array_merge(
                         $participants[$participant],
                         $conferance_participants[$conferance_participant],
                         $contacts[$contact]
                        );

                         $contacts[$contact]['name'] = $cs['name'];

                    }
                }

            }

        }

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($conferance_participants);

    echo "</pre>";
```

The output you should get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 1
            [callee] => yay
            [uid] => 1
            [limit] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [calleridnum] => 2
            [callee] => yay
            [uid] => 2
            [limit] => 1
        )

)
```

I hope that answers your question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

After merging, you may filter only certain keys you want to be present in final result using `array_intersect_key()`.

```
$keys = array_flip(['calleridnum', 'callee', 'uid', 'limit']);

$conferance_participants[$conferance_participant] =
    array_intersect_key(
        array_merge(
            $participants[$participant],
            $conferance_participants[$conferance_participant],
            $contacts[$contact]
        ),
        $keys
    );
```